# If equation has no roots

Tags: python, math

I'm writing a function that solves equations. 
And if an equation has no roots, is it correctly to set to x's ***None*** type?
Or I will get some problems with that in the future and there is a better variant?

Comment: It depends on the language you want to use...

Comment: Don't forget, an equation is likely to have *imaginary* roots, and Python includes complex as a native type. So you can solve for `x² = -1` as `x = 0+1j`. Try it for yourself, at the interpreter type: `(-1+0j)**0.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a *program* or a function? If it's a program, something that will be invoked by people, the right way is to output the phrase "No solutions" or something like that.

Now, if it's a function that returns variable(s), the question is different. First, not all languages have a `None` as a possible numeric value; C/C++, for example, does not. Does the code solve any kind of equation? In that case, consider this. An equation may have multiple roots. That means you should somehow return a collection of roots. If there are no roots, an empty collection would be the right thing to return.

Also, an equation may have an infinite number of roots (example: `0*x=0`).

Comment: sin(x)=1/2 would be a bit less trivial. :-)